# Charting a Alphabetical data based on number of times its repeated in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet that has these kind of values in one of the columns:

```````````
ColumName
``````````
Very Good
Bad
Good
Very Good
Very Good
Good
```````````

etc..

I am trying to insert a pie chart which shows how many times `very good` is repeated and so on. How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table would let you this quickly and without formulas.

- Select your table (in your example, just this one column), including the header name
- Click "Insert PivotTable"
- Click OK.

An empty PivotTable is created. On the field list on the right, you see one field which has your column's name.

- Drag and drop the field to the Row Labels section below.
- Drag it once more to the Values section below. It should show "Count of column name". (If not, you must set it to count).

You should now have a table with the number of occurences for each item.

- Insert Chart.

Comment: I Wanted to vote up your answer as well but I dont have enough points sorry!